# Domain of $f(x)=\log_3\frac{x-1}{x+1}+\sqrt{2x+1} -\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\log_3\frac{x-1}{x+1}+\sqrt{2x+1} -\frac{1}{x}$$
First:

$\sqrt{2x+1}\ge0$,

$1.$ $x_1\ge-\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{x}$  ,

$2.$ $x_2\neq0$

We can't have log of negative number so:

$\log_3\frac{x-1}{x+1}\ge 0$

$3.$ $x_3\neq-1$

$x_1$ tells me that $x$ should be bigger then -1/2, let's say if we put x=-2 
 (as -2<-1/2) in the log we get $-3/-1=3$ which is good. I am not sure what is the domain of this function.

Comment: Think about the “common” ground, I.e. values of $x$ which can satisfy all the requirements. Moreover, for the logarithmic function, you should have $\frac{x-1}{x+1}>0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

We need to solve the system

- $\frac{x-1}{x+1}>0$
- $x\neq -1$
- $2x+1\ge0$
- $x\neq 0$

that is solve each condition and consider the intersection of the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_3\frac{x-1}{x+1}\ge 0$$

**This is wrong**

You need $$\frac{x-1}{x+1}> 0  $$ and $$x\ne -1$$

Similarly, solve $2x+1\ge 0$ and $x\ne0$ take intersection of all the solutions you get